# Kotlin Multiplatform Library: Unable to generate .framework for iOS

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am new to Android/KotlinMultiplatform , I am trying to create a library for iOS/Android using Kotlin Multiplatform.

When I run the command on terminal
`./gradlew :shared:packForXcode`
It succeeds but could not find a `/build/xcode-frameworks` folder inside the root folder.

Could anyone help me to find where it is going wrong...?

IntelliJ CE Version : 2020.2.3

My Gradle file Content:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform") version "1.4.10"
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
    "maven-publish"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

group "me.myname"
version "0.0.1"

kotlin {
    targets {
        android()
        ios {
            binaries {
                framework {
                    baseName = "MyLib"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9")
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies { }
        }
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies { }
        }
    }

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")

    /// selecting the right configuration for the iOS
    /// framework depending on the environment
    /// variables set by Xcode build
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName: String? = System.getenv("SDK_NAME")
    val isiOSDevice = sdkName.orEmpty().startsWith("iphoneos")

    val framework = kotlin.targets
        .getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(
            if(isiOSDevice) {
                "iosArm64"
            } else {
                "iosX64"
            }
        )
        .binaries.getFramework(mode)

    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)

    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)

    println("Build Folder => $targetDir")

    /// generate a helpful ./gradlew wrapper with embedded Java path
    doLast {
        val gradlew = File(targetDir, "gradlew")
        gradlew.writeText("#!/bin/bash\n"
                + "export 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\n"
                + "cd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n"
                + "./gradlew \$@\n")
        gradlew.setExecutable(true)
    }
}

tasks.build.dependsOn("packForXCode")
```

**UPDATE**

1. Project Created using IntelliJ IDEA, as below screenshot:

[image]

2. My project structure looks like below:

[image]

Comment: You should find it in `shared/build/bin/iosX64`

Comment: @shadowsheep I haven't created any folder named "shared"... so I can't find shared folder

Comment: post you project/library structure so we can see how did you name your common shared project. This is your `shared` folder.

Comment: @shadowsheep Project was generated by IntelliJ IDEA , I just updated the build.gradle.kts to above mentioned content

Comment: under build folder I could see two folders:
1) kotlinSourceSetMetadata
2) tmp.


Cannot find "xcode-frameworks" folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've only been able to see the template of your screenshot by using

**IntelliJ 2020.2.3 Ultimate**

This template doesn't have the `packForXcode` task set by default, so you would have put it by hands I suppose.

Anyway, with a **cleaned** project, if you run it, you could have the debug framework in the `build` folder where you want to have it.

[image]

You should have, of course, at least one source (`Greeting.kt`) file like the one I've shown you in my pic.

I suggest you to look deep at the documentation starting from [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html) and [here](https://kotlinlang.org/lp/mobile/).

Comment: You are right!! "packForXcode" was not from default template!! As you suggested I created a "Greeting.kt" and it worked :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, this task is not designed to be executed manually. It should be triggered as a part of the Xcode project build, see in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/discover-kmm-project.html#ios-application). Please try to follow the steps from the documentation, and see if the framework connects and works fine from Xcode.

Comment: That’s not true. You can run it manually too, as a single gradle task.

Comment: I tried from Xcode as well, still I cannot locate the framework...

Comment: @Rameez Could you please tell me if this is some kind of a tutorial code, or it was created by IDEA?

Comment: @shadowsheep you probably can, but what for? The whole reason for this task's existence is to catch env variables set by the Xcode build and configure the framework appropriately. If it is needed to compile the framework manually, one could use ordinary `link<Debug|Release>FrameworkIos<targetName>`.

Comment: Yup, but the OP is saying he cannot find the generated framework that could be generated also by launching the task manually. So that's the main issue of this question I see. For a complete set-up, he should follow the documentation you provided for sure.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev it was generated by IntelliJ IDEA.. I updated the Gradle content with above mentioned code. 
I have update the question with my project structure.

Comment: I m trying to create a Multiplatform Library not a Multiplatform project. I should be able to generate a .framework for iOS and library for android and use It in my iOS/Android projects respectively.